# How do I show a Next button on Sencha NavigationView?

Tags: view, sencha-touch-2

Sencha adds a nice Back button to the navigation bar. As shown below.

[image: Back button in NavigationView]

So my questions are:-

- How can I dynamically add the Next button to the navigation bar?
- How do I style the Next button to have a triangular edge, similar to what the Back button has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change appearance of button to look alike forward button by setting `ui : "forward"` config for button.

You can add buttons to navigation bar with following way -

```
    navigationBar : {           
        items:[
            {
                xtype:'button',
                text:'Forward',
                ui:'forward'
            }
        ]
    },
```

You can also add buttons dynamically to navigation bar from controller. First get instance of navigation view and then navigation bar. Create some buttons and add them to it.

```
   var navBar = this.getMyNavView().getNavigationBar();
    var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Button'
    });
    navBar.add(button);
```

---

**update**
Found this issue for `ui : 'forward'` on sencha forum. Have a look at it.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?253899-When-using-ui-forward-and-back-the-buttons-are-not-being-rendered-properly

Comment: +1 for updating your answer with the rendering issue in chrome. That saved me some time.

Comment: @MathewLeger when i tried that on my chrome it was not rendering properly. It appeared same as snaps in above link. So I searched if it's a real bug or just issue with my css.

Comment: Tip. If you want to present your forward button on the right then add `align: 'right'`.