# manually go back into previous screen in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a custom title bar as follows where i have 3 buttons

```
1) which leads to previous screen
2) back record 
3) next record
```

[image]

here is the code of custom titlebar

```
     {
        xtype : 'titlebar',
        title : 'Contacts',
        items : [{

                  ui:'back',text:'-', aling: 'left'  , action:'fback'

            },{
                ui: 'back', text: 'back', align : 'left', action: 'back'
            },{
                ui: 'forward', text: 'next', align : 'right', action: 'next'
            }]
    }
```

now when i catch the event in controller for `fback` i am firing `history.back()` to go back to the previous screen , but its not working even `tap` event is firing.

i am using this custom title because i dont how to add `prev` and `next` button in `navigation view`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the browser's history you should implement [Routes](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-routes).

Take a look at: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/history_support

Otherwise, you got to extend navigationView [adding a next button to the navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637878/how-do-i-show-a-next-button-on-sencha-navigationview) and then find someway to restore the 'next' view.